# How to edit a class with Jquery ? (delete and add property to an existing class)

Tags: jquery, css

I have a class in CSS:

```
.class {
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

With jQuery how can I edit that class and create a new class like the below?

```
.class {
    color: #777777;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Assuming the styles are set within the page you could do this, but please don't. Why do you want this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.class').css('border-bottom', 'none');
```

Comment: This would work, but keep in mind this changes the style of the elements that have the ".class" class, not the style associated to the class itself. For example, a new element added to the DOM would still have the original style.

Comment: Correct, this would only remove it from the DOM. To remove this permanently, it would have to be taken care of in the stylesheet. Or you can have class1 and class2 with different versions and switch them based on requirement.

Comment: doesn't work....
I have a class that defines me some things of a div using jquery doing some operations, and practically at the click () I want the div lose some properties of the class (so delete these properties giving a null value) or has new. I tried to do this as you said (through css ()) does not work ... checking from firebug I noticed that adds properties to the element but does not change the existing class ... how you can change your class?